# undefined method `send_file' for #<ActionView::Base:0x5fb3650>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a link to download a file from the file system. For this, I define the following in the "license_helper.rb" file:

```
def license_download_link(license, link_text = nil)
    if link_text.blank?
      link_text = image_tag("download_icon.png", :border => 0, :width => 32, :height =>32,  :alt => 'Download License', :title => 'Download License')
    end

    licenseFileId = license.asset.serial_number
    send_file '#{licenseFileId}license.xml', :type => "application/xml", :filename => "#{licenseFileId}license.xml"
    #send_file ' "#{licenseFileId}license.xml" ', :disposition => 'inline'
    #send_file("#{licenseFileId}license.xml", :type => :xml)
    #link_to link_text, '#{"C:\\Entitlement\\trunk\\entitlement_site\\entitlement\\25license.xml"}'
end
```

My "view" just calls this helper class:

```
<td><%= license_download_link(license, ' ') %></td>
```

When I try to view the page, I get the following error message:

```
undefined method `send_file' for #<ActionView::Base:0x5fb3650>
```

As you can see, I tried a bunch of ways to call "send_file", but always get the same error message. Any help would be really appreciated,
Thanks for your time,
Regards,
--- AJ

Answer (score 8):

You need to call `send_file` from a controller action not from your view. The controller action is called in response to the user clicking on a link to it.

In the view you just need need a link to the controller action.

---

The details would depend on your exact application but here is a rough outline of how the parts would fit together

Generate a controller:

```
class LicenceController < ApplicationController
  def download
    # look up the licence and then use send_file
  end
end
```

You can then edit `config/routes.rb` to make a friendly URL for the licence downloads e.g.

```
match 'licences/:id/download' => 'licence#download', :as => 'licence_download'
```

This would mean that URLs of the form `licences/xyz/download` would call your `download` controller method and that a `licence_download_url` helper method would be automatically created for you.

Then in your view you can do

```
<%= link_to 'Download your licence', licence_download_url(licence) %>
```

If you wanted to create a helper method for generating your links with a download icon you could do that too.

If you're quite new to Rails and are struggling with how the parts of an application fit together then [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) would be a good book to get hold of.

Comment: Thanks for you response, appreciate it. I get your point, realized that 'send_file' is part of ActionController and not ActionView. So, if I have the '*_helper.rb' which defines the download link, how do I actually call the 'send_file' method in the controller?

Comment: Have updated the answer with some example code. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot "mikej", will try this out and let you know if it works for me, or rather if I am able to get it to work or not. I tried the above implementation, but wasn't sure about editing the 'config/routes.rb' file. I did borrow the book you mentioned from one of my colleagues, will check it out as well. Thanks once again, and will let you know if I am finally able to get this working or not. Appreciate your time,

Comment: Hi 'Mike', I think I understand the logic and should be able to get this working. I am currently populating a fixed 'id', need to change the DB to have this value. Also, had to use 'map' instead of 'match' as am working with rails 2.3.8. I really appreciate your help, thanks for helping me get there...

Comment: Hi Mike, I am still having problems with this implementation. This is what I have so far,

Comment: Hi, have you edited the question to update it with what you have currently?